# Multiple entities based on single view

Tags: java, jpa, orm, oracle11g, eclipselink

I'm making a domain model based on a remote database schema that only provides a single view for me to work on. The view is a full join of many different tables, which means there is a lot of duplicated data.

The view looks a bit like this (it's actually much bigger, but the idea is the same):

```
STUDENT_ID     STUDENT_NAME     CLASS_ID     CLASS_NAME     YEAR_ID     YEAR
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              Jane             1            Maths          1           2001
1              Jane             2            Biology        1           2001
2              Adam             2            Biology        1           2001
2              Adam             2            Biology        2           2002
NULL           NULL             1            Maths          2           2002
3              Pete             NULL         NULL           NULL        NULL
NULL           NULL             3            Physics        NULL        NULL
NULL           NULL             NULL         NULL           3           2003
```

As we can see, it's a full join of the tables `STUDENT`, `CLASS` and `YEAR`.

Some students are

I want to make 3 Entity classes: `Student`, `Class` and `Year`; each holding an ID and name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THE_VIEW")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME")
    private String name;

    /* Getters, setters and references to other entities */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "THE_VIEW")
public class Clazz implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLASS_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CLASS_NAME")
    private String name;

    /* Getters, setters and references to other entities */
}
```

Will I be able to use `STUDENT_ID` and `CLASS_ID` as `@Id`s? They are not unique in the view, but doing something like `SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME FROM THE_VIEW` would make them unique... How does JPA handle these things?

Using a compound primary key for all the ID:s IS of course possible but it would have to contain MANY fields and I really want to avoid that.

Any other suggestions on solving this? We can disregard the relations to the other entity types for now.

The JPA implementation is eclipselink 2.2.0 and the database is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the real tables, not this view.  Restricting yourself to this makes no sense.  I assume you app is read-only?  Can't see how you could write to this view.

If you must use the view, then create an objects that maps to it, and define your real model objects as Embedded.

i.e.

```
@Entity
public StudentClassAssignment {
  @EmbeddedId
  StudentClassAssignmentId
  @Embedded
  Student student
  @Embedded
  SchoolClass schoolClass      
  @Embedded
  Year year
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have read access to the tables themselves. According to the admin of that database, "the data is all there" (which is true), and he refuses to give me access to the tables.

Comment: Your example doesn't really answer my question though. The `@EmbeddedId` you are using would be huge (10+ fields) in my case, so I want to know if it's possible to have an `@Id` field to a column that isn't really unique in the view. I basically want the result of `SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME FROM THE_VIEW`.

Comment: No, the @Id column needs to be mapped on a field that uniquely identifies the record.